# Error While showing the progress of electron auto updater

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to show the progress of update downloading and i have write the following lines.

```
autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (ev, progress) => {
let log_message = "Download speed: " + progress.bytesPerSecond;
log_message = log_message + ' - Downloaded ' + progress.percent + '%';
log_message = log_message + ' (' + progress.transferred + "/" + progress.total + ')';
sendStatusToWindow(log_message);
```

})

I am using NSIS for update. Now when it is about to download the update, it throws an error below!

[You can see the error in the image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9H4O.png)

Please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead update your question with the content of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using the electron built in module for autoUpdater.
Taking a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/auto-updater.md#events) shows that there is no event 'download-progress'.

In order to listen to that event you can use the 'electron-updater' module as described [here](https://www.electron.build/auto-update#event-download-progress).

Quick overview

1. Install electron-updater as an app dependency.
2. Configure publish section
3. Use autoUpdater from electron-updater instead of electron